# What the difference between vector<T> and vector<class T> is?

Tags: c++

```
class Bar{
};

int main() {
vector<Bar> v1;
vector<class Bar> v2;
}
```

What is the difference between v1 and v2?

Comment: As the code stands, effectively nothing. `v2` uses a forward declaration on `Bar`. Because `Bar` is already declared, this is meaningless.

Comment: `class` is redundant.

Comment: @Rotem Please do not use comments to answer questions. If you think you have an answer to the question, post it as an actual answer.

Comment: @Xirema While I agree, when I'm short on time I prefer to post a helpful comment rather than a bad answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *elaborated-type-specifier* `class Bar` is often used as a forward declaration, but that is not its sole purpose.

First, when you write `class Bar`, the compiler will always search enclosing scopes until it finds a *type* named `Bar`, if possible. So if you have both a class named `Bar` and a function named `Bar` in the same scope or a nested scope, then `class Bar` unambiguously denotes the class. In your program, `Bar` has only been declared once, as a class. However, it's possible to write some convoluted code like this:

```
#include <vector>
class Bar {};
int Bar(class Bar*) {}

int main() {
    std::vector<Bar> v1;        // error! `Bar` refers to the function; the type is hidden
    std::vector<class Bar> v2;  // `class Bar` refers to the class
}
```

(This may seem perverse to you, but the C library has a function called `stat` that takes an argument of type `struct stat*`. So C++ has to be backward-compatible with such code.)

If it turns out that `Bar` has not yet been declared, then `class Bar` serves as a forward declaration. As the OP mentioned in their own answer, you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<class Bar> v2;
class Bar{};
```

However, this can have unintuitive effects, so I suggest avoiding it. For example, what happens in the following code?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
class Foo {
    std::vector<class Bar> v2;
    class Bar{};
    static_assert(std::is_same<Bar, decltype(v2)::value_type>::value);
};
```

Surprise! The `static_assert` *fails*. This is because the forward declaration actually declared a class named `Bar` in the *global* namespace, so it's a different type from the `Foo::Bar` class that is defined on the next line.

In order to avoid issues like this, it would have been better to write the code like this:

```
class Foo {
    class Bar;            // forward declaration on this line
    std::vector<Bar> v2;  // no forward declaration on this line
    class Bar{};
};
```

Here, the forward declaration will do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see.

I can write this:

```
vector<class Bar> v2;
class Bar{};
```

But I can't write that:

```
vector<Bar> v2;
class Bar{};
```